# Выбрать ли PHP?

Tags: php, c++

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь разобраться на чем лучше сделать?
Есть некая железка на процессоре arm c Linux, которая измеряет разные датчики: температуру, давление и т.д.  Задача состоит в том, чтобы иметь доступ к этим данным через Web. Уволившемся программистом было почти все сделано: веб-сервер apache выдает страничку с Flash, которая через SOAP запрашивает данные у некоего демона написанного на С, который в свою очередь получает данные от основной программы, занимающейся измерениями. Но концепция поменялось, и от Flash решено отказаться в пользу AJAX, тяжеловесный SOAP заменить на REST c JSON, а демона собирающего данные и упаковывающего в JSON вроде тоже можно заменит, но на что? 
Поскольку с Web разбираюсь всего месяц, а до этого программировал железки на С, то хотелось бы узнать мнения более опытных коллег..

С вашей помощью, вот что у меня получается:
 1. источник данных пишет в MySQL, python/perl/php забирает данные и выдает наружу;
 2. python/perl/php получает данные от источника данных через виртуальную память, сам пишет в MySql и выдает наружу;
 3. Вариант 2, но вместо python/perl/php использовать С

Появляются доп. вопросы: 
 1. Какой выигрыш в % производительности даст С, т.е. вариант 3.
 2. Что больше подойдет MySql или Sqlite.

Comment: зачем тебе вообще бд? для такой задачи вполне хватает лог-файла

Comment: ИМХО Вам придется вообще, практически, все переписать!

Comment: исходя из того что у вас железка с не очень сильным процессором, C/C++ предпочтительнее.

Comment: Если у меня много разных датчиков, которые постоянно пишут свои данные(допустим раз в 10мс), потом клиент хочет посмотреть тренды за разные периоды времени, надо делать выборки за день, за год и т.д. Думаю с БД будет удобнее?

Comment: ну в таком случае лучше бд, но все же я бы делал промежуточный лог-файл, с него читал и дальше писал в бд, т.е. это надо для того что бы было легче снимать данные с датчиков - скрипт пишет в лог, с лога читаем раз в день, лог удаляется.... как-то так...

Comment: Железка ARM9 454МГц.. Новый программист всегда хочет переписать, весь непонятный ему код под себя :)

Comment: "Recently, Facebook provided us with some information on their server park. They use about 30,000 servers, and not surprisingly, most of them are running PHP code to generate pages full of social info for their users. As they only say that 'the bulk' is running PHP, let's assume this to be 25,000 of the 30,000. If C++ would have been used instead of PHP, then 22,500 servers could be powered down (assuming a conservative ratio of 10 for the efficiency of C++ versus PHP code), or a reduction of 49,000 tons of CO2 per year. Of course, it is a bit unfair to isolate Facebook here"

Comment: Пишем на С экономим кислород:)

Answer (score 3):

> SOAP заменить на JSON

SOAP можно заменить на REST, JSON на ХML =)

дальше если есть источник данных мониторинга, то в общем всеравно, можно и PHP, наверно, даже проще будет, если умеешь... имеется ввиду веб-сервис

> а вот демона собирающего данные вроде
> можно сделать на PHP?

вот эта - вряд ли, так как лучше, имхо, сделать скрипты, которые будут мониторить систему, писать лог, а лога читать пхп или тут уже всеравно и отправлять дальше..

Answer (score 1):

JSON - хорошо, pyhon|perl лучше чем php. Если хотите выжать максимум скорости, можете использовать C с библиотекой Fast CGI. Apache тяжеловесный заменить на nginx или что ещё по-проще, лишь бы fastCGI поддерживал.